# forms passing from user input to cgi address in form action

Tags: html, forms

This is what I want to output.

```
http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text="WHAT USER INPUTS"
```

and I'm not getting any love no matter what I do, this is what i have...

```
 <form action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=" method="post">
 <label for="mestext1"></label>
 <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="80">
 <div class="floatright">Titles can be up to 80 Characters... upload file if beyond 80 chars &nbsp<input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">
```

right now i'm not getting anything from the user input...
I'm getting this...

```
http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `name` attribute on your `<input>`.  So:

```
 <form action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace" method="post">
   <label for="mestext1"></label>
   <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="80" name="text">
   <div class="floatright">Titles can be up to 80 Characters... upload file if beyond 80 chars &nbsp
   <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">
   ...
</form>
```

Note the `name="text"` on the input tag, and no need for `&text=` on the action value.

Also, you are doing a `POST`, so you will not see the submitted form values in the URL.  That only happens if you use `method="GET"`.  (`POST` is still probably correct though.)

Comment: I made the changes and the content still doesn't go into the address string.

Comment: <legend>Title 1</legend> 
 <form action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=" method="post">
  <label for="mestext1"></label>
  <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="80" name="text">
  <div class="floatright">Titles can be up to 80 Characters... upload file if beyond 80 chars &nbsp>
<input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">  </div><br>
  </form><br><br />

Comment: Not sure what you mean by address string.  If you expect to see the text input value in the URL, then you need to change your `post` to a `get`, like I said.

Comment: Also, remove `&text=` from your `action`, like I said.  It will be added for you.